# How to give NPCs random movement?

Tags: random, pico-8

I'm making a PICO-8 game that has 3 separate NPCs. I want to give each one a movement system so that when they move, they choose a random place on the screen, go towards it, and upon reaching it, choose a new random spot and head towards that; rinse and repeat.

Someone told me that I should use the Euclidean Distance Formula to make them (an NPC) move towards a spot, and then calculate their movement based on that, which I tried to do, but I'm nowhere near as advanced as them, so I'm not able to implement this on my own.

This is everything I have for movement so far:

```
function cleric_movement()
        cleric_dx = rnd(2) - 1
        cleric_dy = rnd(2) - 1
        
        cleric_target_x = rnd(128)
        cleric_target_y = rnd(128)

        d = sqrt((cleric_target_x - cleric_c)^2 + (cleric_target_y - cleric_y)^2

        cleric_x += sgn(cleric_dx)
        cleric_y += sgn(cleric_dy)
        
        cleric_stop_at_edge()
end

function cleric_stop_at_edge()
  if (cleric_x<0) cleric_x=0
  if (cleric_x>111) cleric_x=111
  if (cleric_y<0) cleric_y=0
  if (cleric_y>111) cleric_y=111
end
```

And just to be clear, each NPC should pick ***their own target x and y variables!!***

Thanks for any help!

P.S. If anyone knows a better place to post a question about PICO-8, since this site doesn't have a lot of PICO questions (31 with this one) and there probably won't be a lot of people familiar with it, please tell me where I can bring this.

Answer (score 0):

I would generate the target location like this:

1. Choose an angle, A, between 0 and 360 degrees
2. Choose a distance, d, that the NPC must travel
3. Compute the dx and dy values from the angle and distance:

```
dx = d * cos(A)
dy = d * sin(A)
```

4. If the NPC is located at the coordinates (x, y), check whether (x + dx, y + dy) is a valid location on the map:

- If this *is* a valid location, then move towards it.
- If this is *not* a valid location, then attempt to generate a new target location.

This algorithm has the advantage of keeping the walking speed constant and reasonable for the NPCs.

If an NPC gets backed into a corner, then they might have to reroll their target location several times, but they will get out almost immediately.

Comment: Why do you use cos() for dx and sin() for dy?

Comment: It's the formula for the position of a point on a circle in polar coordinates. You choose the radius (d) and the angle (A), and then you find the point on the circle. It's nicer, because you can choose how far the NPC has to walk (d) and you can choose the direction he takes (A).

Comment: If you choose dx and dy, then you have to compute the distance the NPC walks. It could be near, or far, depending on the dx and dy values that you chose--which means his walking speed will be variable, which could feel strange to the player.